# When I try to send something,the TCP connection will abort,

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, tcp

Today I try to use `TCP` to send 2 files to [Awaaaaawwwwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13909368/awaaaaawwwwa) (her use linux,qq for linux can't receive file),but when I try to send something after I receive her packet,there is a `Exception` happend.
`Exception`:

```java
java.net.SocketException：Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0 (本机方法)
at SocketOutputStream.socketWrite (SocketOutputStream.java:110)
at SocketOutputStream.socketWrite (SocketOutputStream.java:110)
at (#34:1)
```

java code:

```java
ServerSocket server=new ServerSocket(8888);
server.accept();
$2.getInputStream();
$2.getOutputStream();
$3.read();
$4.write(new String("i received your packet".getBytes(),"UTF-8").getBytes());
$4.flush();
```

nodejs code:

```js
const net=require('net');
let client=net.Socket();
client.connect(42231,'222.186.174.9',()=>{console.log('done');});
client.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});
client.write("1");
```

Intranet penetration software: Sakura Frp,server: 镇江电信
Develop environment:java 11 jshell and nodejs

Comment: First, ServerSocket binds to your localhost at port 8888, and starts listening for connections.  If you want to connect to someone else, then use Socket, not ServerSocket.  My guess is that you are not connected to anyone, so the socket connection fails when you try to send anything.

Comment: The code does not look like the code for the TCP client, but the TCP server. You must use Socket class.